# Message box popup in the background

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
String message = "Are you sure the event: \"" + event_text + "\" has been complete for Loan# " + loannumber + "?"; //show popup to confirm the completion of event

var result = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(message, "Loan # "+loannumber+" - Processed Event: "+event_text, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
{

    //do nothing close popup
}
else
{

//do something else
```

I have this code behind on my ASP.NET page.  When I click a button on my webpage, this popup should show up.  The problem is that sometimes it shows up in the foreground, but sometimes I have to actually click on the little icon on the doc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Um.  Are you showing Windows Forms dialogs on the server from your ASP.NET application?

Comment: yes...I am is that a problem?

Comment: When I use javascript it works fine however I can get the variables I need.

Comment: I suppose it's not necessarily a "problem", but the end user will never see these dialogs.  You probably see them when you run this from your development environment because your Dev PC is the client *and* the server.

Answer (score 2):

It is unusual to show a server side dialog as part of a web application. That will block the thread for the web server, and the user (unless they are sitting at the web server console, rather than in their home/office with a web browser) won't see it.

I think you want to do a client side popup - perhaps with a javascript Alert or a HTML dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a MessageBox.

If you need to fire a JavaScript alert message from the code-behind, try using the ScriptManager.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "clientScript", "alert('hi');", true)
```

The code above uses the page to register the script and fire off the alert message. The final parameter *true*, indicates the the  tags will open and close around the script you provided.